# when initializing Hive for the first-time getting error on hive-site.xml

Tags: hive, hive-metastore

I am unable to find the cause of the below error as it points to hive-site.xml
so far what I have configured is completely correct.
FYI i am using hadoop 3.1.1 and hive 3.1.1 and mysql for hive metastore.

```
adminn@master:~$ schematool -initSchema -dbType mysql

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: com.ctc.wstx.exc.WstxParsingException: Illegal character entity: expansion character (code 0x8
 at [row,col,system-id]: [3210,96,"file:/home/adminn/apache-hive-3.1.1-bin/conf/hive-site.xml"]
    at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.loadResource(Configuration.java:3003)
    at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.loadResources(Configuration.java:2931)
    at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getProps(Configuration.java:2806)
    at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.get(Configuration.java:1460)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.conf.HiveConf.getVar(HiveConf.java:4990)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.conf.HiveConf.getVar(HiveConf.java:5063)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.conf.HiveConf.initialize(HiveConf.java:5150)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.conf.HiveConf.<init>(HiveConf.java:5098)
    at org.apache.hive.beeline.HiveSchemaTool.<init>(HiveSchemaTool.java:96)
    at org.apache.hive.beeline.HiveSchemaTool.main(HiveSchemaTool.java:1473)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.run(RunJar.java:318)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:232)
Caused by: com.ctc.wstx.exc.WstxParsingException: Illegal character entity: expansion character (code 0x8
 at [row,col,system-id]: [3210,96,"file:/home/adminn/apache-hive-3.1.1-bin/conf/hive-site.xml"]
    at com.ctc.wstx.sr.StreamScanner.constructWfcException(StreamScanner.java:621)
    at com.ctc.wstx.sr.StreamScanner.throwParseError(StreamScanner.java:491)
    at com.ctc.wstx.sr.StreamScanner.reportIllegalChar(StreamScanner.java:2456)
    at com.ctc.wstx.sr.StreamScanner.validateChar(StreamScanner.java:2403)
    at com.ctc.wstx.sr.StreamScanner.resolveCharEnt(StreamScanner.java:2369)
    at com.ctc.wstx.sr.StreamScanner.fullyResolveEntity(StreamScanner.java:1515)
    at com.ctc.wstx.sr.BasicStreamReader.nextFromTree(BasicStreamReader.java:2828)
    at com.ctc.wstx.sr.BasicStreamReader.next(BasicStreamReader.java:1123)
    at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration$Parser.parseNext(Configuration.java:3257)
    at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration$Parser.parse(Configuration.java:3063)
    at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.loadResource(Configuration.java:2986)
    ... 15 more
```

given below is the hive-site.xml file where i made the required changes.
some imp part of hive-site.xml

```
  <property>

    <name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionPassword</name>

    <value>Hivehadoop@123$</value>

    <description>password to use against metastore database</description>

  </property>

  <property>

    <name>hive.metastore.ds.connection.url.hook</name>

    <value/>

    <description>Name of the hook to use for retrieving the JDO connection URL. If empty, the value in javax.jdo.option.ConnectionURL is used</description>

  </property>

  <property>

    <name>javax.jdo.option.Multithreaded</name>

    <value>true</value>

    <description>Set this to true if multiple threads access metastore through JDO concurrently.</description>

  </property>

  <property>

    <name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionURL</name>

    <value>jdbc:mysql://localhost/metastore_db?createDatabaseIfNotExist=true</value>

    <description>

      JDBC connect string for a JDBC metastore.

      To use SSL to encrypt/authenticate the connection, provide database-specific SSL flag in the connection URL.

      For example, jdbc:postgresql://myhost/db?ssl=true for postgres database.

    </description>

  </property>
  <property>

    <name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionUserName</name>

    <value>hiveuser</value>

    <description>Username to use against metastore database</description>

  </property>

    <property>

    <name>hive.exec.local.scratchdir</name>

    <value>/tmp/${user.name}</value>

    <description>Local scratch space for Hive jobs</description>

  </property>

  <property>

    <name>hive.downloaded.resources.dir</name>

    <value>/tmp/${user.name}_resources</value>

    <description>Temporary local directory for added resources in the remote file system.</description>

  </property>
```

Comment: Show your XML file

Comment: yes sure, i have added now

Answer (score 1):

this is solved, i removed the special character form the specified line number. then its working fine.